# What's better: to record or develop tests via CodedUI?

Tags: ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I must create test automation framework for web application with CodedUI. MSDN advises to record all steps. But recording via CodedUI generates a lot of code and it is not very clear.
I think that it will be more useful to record only locators of elements on the page and then write code for interaction with these elements. Can somebody answer: which approach is better - record steps or implement тэм by myself?

Answer (score 0):

In all the automated UI frameworks that I have worked with thus far (Winrunner, QTP and CUIT) I have found that record and playback is good for small, mostly throwaway type items.

If you want to build a large suite that is managable for you, try each of the approaches in a POC and see what works for for your project.

In my current case, I tried the record and playback with CUIT and the Object Map/code method. Then I found [CUITe](http://cuite.codeplex.com) and the layout of that made a lot more sense to me based on what I had previously worked on, so I went with that.

That said, a lot people in my org still do record & play and/or use the UIMaps + hand coded UI tests.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to develop your own test, and not to record.
for best practice you should record and then investigate the code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Working in generic way it's always better then working in un generic way. I recommend to you to develop the tests becouse you will learn better and you can find easly more bugs in your code then a generate code by CUIT. I also recommend to record just the main window of the application and to navigate inside the apllication by functions. when you reach to an object you can get and set a lot of properties then you just record him. for example: you can ask if the object exist before you start using him, somthing that you can't do when you record.